# Python string encoding: An extra backslash added to strings when sent over http

Tags: python, string, unicode, httprequest

When I post a string `"\u062c\u0646\u062f\u064a\u0651\u0627"` via an HTTP request it is received as the following `'\\u062c\\u0646\\u062f\\u064a\\u0651\\u0627'`. What are the extra backslashes added for? And how to strip them?

Comment: Extra forward slashes are used to escape the originals, because the originals would otherwise cause the character(s) following to be interpreted as escape codes themselves. On this occasion python recognises that \u is not a valid escape code so inserts the extra backslashes, because those are the rules.

Comment: Could everyone just stop calling backslashes forward slashes, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

… how to strip them?

```
s_sent     = "\u062c\u0646\u062f\u064a\u0651\u0627"
s_received = '\\u062c\\u0646\\u062f\\u064a\\u0651\\u0627'
s_sent == s_received.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
```

> ```
> True
> ```